# How can I document tables and fields in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I've missed this somehow in my SQL Server learning process.

I'd like to be able to document tables/fields/procedures in our SQL Server 2005 environment, and I can't find a way to do this.  Is this possible, or would I need a third party app of some kind?

This sounds like a no-brainer feature, so I'm probably overlooking it.

Thanks!

JH

EDIT: Specifially, I'm talking about documenting SQL objects ('this table is used for blah, and is referenced by foo, and bar.').  Thanks for all the help - you guys nailed it.

Comment: What do you mean by document?  Just a list?

Comment: +1 for even wanting to document anything! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL Server has [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) that you can use for this purpose.

Comment: This is excellent - hadn't heard about it, and will fill our needs perfectly.  Kudos.

Answer (score 3):

One of the best documenting tools is called [SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm) by RedGate software.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of tools - I personally really like SQL Doc (by Red-Gate; mentioned before), but also ApexSQL's [ApexSQL Doc](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.asp).

But a lot of other tools also will read and document database schemas - if you already have a help writer, check it out - it might even support database documentation, too!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

With stored_procedures, views, and functions you can simply add a comment syntax to the object definition like:

```
/*
some comment
*/
create view dbo.view sample ...
```

with tables and fields it is a bit more complicated, you can use [Extended Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243.aspx) as suggested by [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701271/how-can-i-document-tables-and-fields-in-sql-server-2005/701303#701303). You can access it through Management Studio by selecting the table in object explored and Properties from context menu.

If you can afford investing in Tools you can pick [SQL Doc](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Doc/index.htm) as suggested by [TheTXI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701271/how-can-i-document-tables-and-fields-in-sql-server-2005/701283#701283)

Answer (score 0):

You should look at www.aphilen.com they have a SQL documentation tool available they may assist with what you arr trying to achieve alternatively you can achieve this all manually if you have the time using sp_help objectname